# VBox shared folders not mounted after Upgrade to Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, guest-additions

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18 LTS, after that I can't see shared folders content as they are not mounted under `/media` ... I tried to restart service with :

```
sudo systemctl restart vboxadd-service.service
```

But with `journalctl -ex` , I observed following error:

> could not run /usr/sbin/VBoxService

I don't know why I get such error?  and how to correct mounting share folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems guest additions might not match your VBox/Ubuntu version (As I upgraded to 18 LTS those were not updated)

I managed to solve by installing guest additions (`Device--> Insert Guest Additions CD`)

when installation started .. it removed old version and installed current version for my VBox.

That my user (osboxes) has no default access to shared volumes can be solved by adding the user to shared folders group:

```
sudo adduser myuser vboxsf
```

**Important Note**:

@Itay and I also observed this solves shared clipboard issues, as after upgrade Ubuntu to 18 LTS and updating guest additions *bidirectional* clipboard worked correctly even it didnt wotk on previous versions.

Comment: Thanks!
Two comments: this also solves the clipboard sharing problem after the update, and I had to restart after adding permissions to myuser.

Comment: @Itay Exactly, yes shared clipboard worked for me only after that .. never worked before!

Comment: It works, that command must be done on the host.